# Как настроить ipfw чтобы Joomla 3 проверяла обновления?

Tags: joomla, freebsd, ipfw

Настраивал файрволл ipfw в FreeBSD, в результате Joomla 3 перестала проверять обновления. Подскажите, какие порты нужно открыть?
Вот текущий список правил.

```
# ipfw list
00015 reject log logamount 10000 tcp from any to any tcpflags syn,fin,ack,psh,rst,urg via ae0
00016 reject log logamount 10000 tcp from any to any tcpflags !syn,!fin,!ack,!psh,!rst,!urg via ae0
00017 reject log logamount 10000 tcp from any to any not established tcpflags fin via ae0
00018 deny log logamount 10000 IP from any to any not verrevpath in via ae0
00050 allow IP from any to any via lo0
00055 allow IP from me to any
00075 allow tcp from any to any established
00100 allow icmp from any to any
00114 allow udp from any to any dst-port 53 out via ae0
00150 allow IP from 192.168.1.1 to me via ae0
00150 allow IP from 192.168.1.5 to me via ae0
00155 allow tcp from me to any keep-state
00170 allow tcp from any to me dst-port 22,10000,80,443,25,465,21 via ae0
00200 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 80 out via ae0.
00225 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 25 out via ae0
00227 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 110 out via ae0
00250 allow icmp from any to any out via ae0 keep-state
00255 allow udp from me to any keep-state
00255 allow IP from any to any dst-port 123 out via ae0
00300 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 22 out via ae0 setup keep-state
00355 allow icmp from me to any keep-state
10000 deny IP from any to any
65535 deny IP from any to any
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь скорее всего проблема не в правилах брандмауэра, а в чём-то другом.

Почему?

Потому что у вас практически в самом начале есть правило

```
00055 allow IP from me to any
```

разрещающее исходящие соединения. Обновления Joomla выполняет, естественно, инициируя соединения со своей стороны. Поэтому они не будут запрещены и будут происходить беспрепятственное.

Попробуйте посмотреть отладочные (debug) сообщения процесса обновления.

Comment: К сожалению отладка joomla не особо информативна вот что в логе nginx 2015/04/07 22:30:35 [error] 1581#0: *591 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.5, server: localhost, request: "POST /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=update HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.7", referrer: "http://192.168.1.7/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=update"

Comment: Вот что еще было.
Warning

Update: Could not open update site #1 "Joomla! Core", URL: http://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml

Update: Could not open update site #2 "Joomla! Extension Directory", URL: http://update.joomla.org/jed/list.xml

Update: Could not open update site #4 "Joomla! Update Component Update Site", URL: http://update.joomla.org/core/extensions/com_joomlaupdate.xml

Comment: заметил, что и freebsd-update fetch не соединяется с зеркалами.

Comment: @Magi: А можно временно ещё убрать три первых правила? Или поставить правила 55 и 75 временно перед ними?

Comment: Попробовал - не помогает...

Answer (score 0):

Для простого WEB сервера этих правил должно хватить:

```
allow ip from any to any via lo0
deny ip from any to 127.0.0.0/8
deny ip from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
allow tcp from any to any established
allow ip from any to any frag
allow tcp from any to me dst-port 25,465,587 setup
allow tcp from any to me dst-port 110,143,995 setup
allow tcp from any to me dst-port 53 setup
allow udp from any to me dst-port 53
allow udp from me 53 to any
allow tcp from any to me dst-port 80,8080,443 setup
allow tcp from any to me dst-port 22 setup
allow tcp from me to any setup
deny tcp from any to any setup
allow udp from me to any dst-port 53 keep-state
allow udp from me to any dst-port 123 keep-state
deny ip from any to any
```